# How to avoid putting dev packages in requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip, dependency-management

I use `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to make sure that others in my project can install all the relevant libraries via `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

The problem is that sometimes I have notebook libraries installed, or IDE specific formatters installed. Maybe I don't want to force my fellow team members to install all this stuff too.

Is there a clean way to do this?

Answer (score 9):

Do it the other way around. Manually write into the file, then install from there.

#### requirements.txt

```
requests
numpy
```

#### dev-requirements.txt

```
pytest
```

Better yet, use [Poetry](http://python-poetry.org/). It solves these issues really nicely.

Comment: I was thinking of writing manually. But doesn't that mean if a library has its own sub-dependencies which automatically come with it, I won't be able to freeze the sub-dependency versions?

Comment: You'd freeze them into a second file, often called a lockfile (`requirements.lock`). Poetry does this automatically and a bunch of other nice things besides.

Answer (score 1):

For this issue, I separate my `requirements.txt`, one of them for development and another for production.

Also I suggest [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to handle this issue easly.